# Output time time between a past date and today php

Tags: php, date, strtotime

At the moment I have a query which check the date from an external website and give me some information if that date is older than four weeks:

```
$json = json_decode($result, true);

echo date("d.m.Y",strtotime($json[lastUpdated][when]));

$mydate = strtotime($json[lastUpdated][when]);

if ($mydate <= strtotime('4 weeks ago')) {
    echo "Is not up to date!";
}
```

And I would like to have an output of how much time has passed between the date `$mydate` and today. Thanks!

Comment: Remark: You probably miss some quotes. Instead of `strtotime($json[lastUpdated][when]` it should be `strtotime($json['lastUpdated']['when']`

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where is your Problem ? Wa are not here to make the work for you. One look at the strtotime return value, and a simple search for php get timestamp would have solved your question!

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo thank you for your note! Thats very helpful too. I had really no idea to solved my own question. But you clever brains helped me. Thanks!

Comment: You should look at the [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) in PHP. It has the ability to diff between two dates keeping track of leap years and other date annoyances. Calculating diff is easy with it, see the [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) on PHP.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply calculate the difference between both dates by using:

```
$mydate = strtotime($json['lastUpdated']['when']); // I guess the quotes are missing in your code
$now = time();
echo "The difference is " . ($now - $mydate) . " seconds";
```

If you need something different then seconds you'll have to calulcate those values, e.g.

```
echo "The difference is " . (($now - $mydate)/60) . " minutes";
echo "The difference is " . (($now - $mydate)/60*60) . " hours";
echo "The difference is " . (($now - $mydate)/60*60*24) . " days";
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you very much!